# I cannot replicate the slope for an ETS model with alpha = 0.5 and beta =0.5 using the model's formula. Misunderstanding or a bug?

Tags: time-series, exponential-smoothing

When I fit an "AAN" ETS model with alpha and beta both equal to 0.5, the level is correct as per the Level equation, but the slope as independently calculated by the Trend equation is not. I have tested this with different data sets.

In the code below I have used Rob Hyndman's example from the video on [Holt's Linear Trend](https://otexts.com/fpp3/holt.html) as an example. His with automatic parameters works fine, but setting alpha and beta manually does not. Perhaps I have the ETS syntax wrong? Or am I expecting the model to be something it is not?

```
library(fpp3)
aus_economy <- global_economy |>  filter(Code == "AUS") |>   mutate(Pop = Population / 1e6)

# Fit a holt linear model with alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.5 and no seasonality
fit <- aus_economy |>
  model(AAN = ETS(Pop ~ error("A") + trend(method = "A", alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.5) + season("N")))

options(pillar.sigfig = 10)  # Need more significant figures for the analysis
report(fit) # Correctly shows AAN model, using alpha = 0.5 and beta = 0.5

summary <- components(fit) |>   left_join(fitted(fit), by = c("Country", ".model", "Year"))
summary

a <- 0.5
b <- 0.5

# Using the Trend formula and the starting values l[0] and b[0]
Slope_at_time_t_trend_formula <- (b*(summary$level[2] - summary$level[1])) + ((1-b)*summary$slope[1]) # Second row of summary
Slope_at_time_t_trend_formula  # Returns 0.2357104

# In numbers (0.5*(10.27089128 - 10.03238802)) + ((1-0.5)*0.2329175516)
Diff <- summary$slope[2] - Slope_at_time_t_trend_formula

summary$slope[2] 
Slope_at_time_t_trend_formula
Diff  #  .002792858 - about 1% so not a rounding error
```

[image: ETS equations]

Comment: The equation in your post uses beta*. The function uses beta. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/ets.html#etsaan-holts-linear-method-with-additive-errors for the connection